# Trouble in using front camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I tried to implement front facing camera in my application. I used the following code. It works fine with the back camera. But I cant change the camera to front camera.

```
package com.fsp.googleimagesearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class PixtantCamera extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    Button btn_capture, btn_front_cam;
    FrameLayout preview;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mCamera != null) {

            // mCamera.stopPreview();
            stopCamera();
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mCamera != null) {

            // mCamera.stopPreview();
            stopCamera();
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pixt_camera);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        btn_front_cam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_front_cam);

        btn_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_cam);
        btn_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });

        btn_front_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {
                    // if you want to open front facing camera use this line
                    mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);              
                try {
                    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(PixtantCamera.this,
                            mCamera);
                    preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    mCamera.release();
                }
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
            }
        });

    }

    public int getFrontCameraId() {
        CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
            if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                return i;
        }
        return -1; // No front-facing camera found
    }



    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public void stopCamera() {
        // mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
        // mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        // private Camera mCamera;

        // Constructor that obtains context and camera
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;
            mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // left blank for now
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // intentionally left blank for a test
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following error.

```
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:353)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:312)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at com.fsp.googleimagesearch.PixtantCamera$3.onClick(PixtantCamera.java:88)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4262)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17351)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-23 23:27:34.260: E/AndroidRuntime(24320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have added the permissions too..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: `mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);` in try catch and check logcat once

Comment: @Pragnani same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you cannot make a second call to `Camera.open()` before releasing the Camera currently held by your app.  Try adding `mCamera.release()` as the first line in your `onClick` method for `btn_front_cam`.

Edit: You also may need

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

as well as

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: @ MattDavis I used mCamera.release(), before open. Still no use. gives this error. 04-24 14:18:54.304: E/Camera(5616): Error -2147483648

Comment: I've looked over your question again and edited my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: My next guess would be that this has something to do with needing to manage the preview when changing cameras, but I've found that the Android camera can be very temperamental and throw errors in any number of places.  Here are the docs for setting up a camera activity, your best bet may be following along with the tutorial and making sure you're performing all the necessary actions at each step. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html